# Invalid scalar projection in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera

I have the data in PIG with column names as

**keyword, campaign_id, date, time, display_site, was_clicked, cpc, country, placement**

What I'm trying to do is finding keywords with high CTR.

So, I'm trying to understand why the following code is giving me Invalid Scalar projection error

```
  grouped = GROUP data BY keyword;
  by_keyword = FOREACH grouped 
{
  clicked = FILTER data BY was_clicked == 1;
  total = COUNT(data.keyword);
  GENERATE group, ((double)COUNT(clicked) / total) AS ctr;
}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
37,632 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse: 
<line 59, column 33> Invalid scalar projection: clicked : A column needs to be projected from a relation for it to be used as a scalar
Details at logfile: /home/cloudera/pig_1486224821223.log
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

```
data = LOAD '/user/cloudera/pig_demo/ad_data.txt' AS (keyword:chararray,campaign_id:chararray,
      date:chararray, time:chararray,display_site:chararray, was_clicked:int, 
      cpc:int, country:chararray, placement:chararray);
```

Sample of the records:

```
tablet  C6  5/1/2013    3:47:10 movienet.example.com    0   102 USA TOP
```

Comment: Can you provide the load statement as well along with a sample record.

Comment: @franklinsijo Provided the sample record and  load statement.

Comment: Not able to reproduce the error. Added few more records of same pattern as `,` delimited text. Works for me!

Comment: @franklinsijo That's strange. Can you help me understand what the error means?

Comment: What is the version of pig you are using?

Comment: @franklinsijo Apache Pig version 0.12.0-cdh5.8.0 (rexported)

Comment: I tried to reproduce in Pig-0.16.0. Can you try replacing the 6th line with   `GENERATE group, ((double)COUNT(clicked.keyword) / total) AS ctr;` and see if it solves. I am projecting a field `keyword` out of the `clicked` relation for COUNT.

Comment: @franklinsijo it's giving the error 120 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1045: 
<line 66, column 26> Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.COUNT as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.
Details at logfile: /home/cloudera/pig_1486224821223.log

Comment: can you do `describe clicked` and post what it gives

Comment: @franklinsijo clicked: {keyword: chararray,campaign_id: chararray,date: chararray,time: chararray,display_site: chararray,was_clicked: int,cpc: int,country: chararray,placement: chararray}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pig version 0.15.

Input file `data.txt`:

```
tablet  C6  5/1/2013    3:47:10 movienet.example.com    0   102 USA TOP
tablet  C6  5/1/2013    3:47:10 movienet.example.com    0   102 USA TOP
tablet  C6  5/1/2013    3:47:10 movienet.example.com    0   102 USA TOP
tablet  C6  5/1/2013    3:47:10 movienet.example.com    1   102 USA TOP
```

Script:

```
data = LOAD '/path/data.txt' AS (keyword:chararray,campaign_id:chararray,
  date:chararray, time:chararray,display_site:chararray, was_clicked:int, 
  cpc:int, country:chararray, placement:chararray);
grouped = GROUP data BY keyword;
by_keyword = FOREACH grouped 
{
  clicked = FILTER data BY was_clicked == 1;
  total = COUNT(data.keyword);
  GENERATE group, ((double)COUNT(clicked) / total) AS ctr;
}
dump by_keyword
```

gives me correct result:

```
(tablet,0.25)
```

Comment: Okay, so restarted PIG in terminal and loaded the data file again and then executed only the above commands. It worked!